# Reactive forms: valueChanges on input field raises error

Tags: angular, ionic2, rxjs, observable

I'm tracking the changes on an input field of a reactive form using the function 'valueChanges', when I write any thing like "abc" works fine,
**But when I remove the text, the error function is raised, and then when I write any thing again 'valueChanges' doesn't fire, here is the sample:**

```
this.searchForm.controls.SearchValue.valueChanges
      .debounceTime(1000)
      .switchMap(term => this._http
    .get(CONFIG.API_ENDPOINT + `/folders/search/` + term))
      .subscribe(
        (result) => {
          this.searchResult = result;
        },
        (err) => {
          console.log(error);
        })
```

I need to know what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.searchForm.controls.SearchValue.valueChanges
      .debounceTime(1000)
      .filter(term => !(term === null || term === ''))
      .switchMap(term => this._http
    .get(CONFIG.API_ENDPOINT + `/folders/search/` + term))
      .subscribe(
        (result) => {
          this.searchResult = result;
        },
        (err) => {
          console.log(error);
        })
```

Comment: You getting the same thing?

Comment: yes after i empty the text input then refill it nothing happened at all

Comment: Ohh sorry, my bad, the condition in filter I said was kinda wrong, I have updated the answer, try now it should be working

Comment: but i needed to enter the error code (console.log(error)) when the item is empty so i can configure something to show and hide the form

Comment: Ohh, in that case you can simply control it with an ngIf="searchForm.value.SearchValue == '' "

Comment: it solve kind of the problem , thanks i change my work to suit your code

Answer (score 3):

Observables work in a way that the stream stops emitting values, once it completes or an error happens.

```
this.searchForm.controls.SearchValue.valueChanges
      .debounceTime(1000)
      .filter(val => val)
      .switchMap(term => {
          return this._http.get(CONFIG.API_ENDPOINT + `/folders/search/` + term)
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
                return Observable.empty()
            })
      })
      .subscribe(result => {
          this.searchResult = result;
      })
```

You can play with the code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-http-r1qe3z (enter numbers).
This video was very helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3LKMwkuK0ZE
26:20 is where it's explained.

Comment: so what should i do ?

Comment: what do you want to happen if the input string is empty?

Comment: i need when i refill the textinput the valueChanges triggered again

Comment: the problem is valueChanges didn't triggered when the value is filled after empty it. so it will not access the debounceTime and switchMap

Comment: is there an error happening in the console? it stops watching changes after you type something and then delete it?

Comment: HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "http://52.174.35.94:8081/gate/api/folders/search/", ok: false, …}
error
:
null
headers
:
HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message
:
"Http failure response for http://52.174.35.94:8081/gate/api/folders/search/: 404 Not Found"
name
:
"HttpErrorResponse"
ok
:
false
status
:
404
statusText
:
"Not Found"
url
:
"http://52.174.35.94:8081/gate/api/folders/search/"

Comment: when the value is empty an error occured because  term will be empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165038/discussion-between-boris-lobanov-and-joe-sleiman).